# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe using python socket module

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Im using hyperskill platform for doing some projects, currently im doing dictionary-based brute force and am still getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "hack.py", line 23, in \<module\>
client_socket.send(message)
BrokenPipeError: \[Errno 32\] Broken pipe
```

Is something wrong with my code, im getting this error nearly every step but it was usually some indent error or some other small mistake, rn i have no clue what is wrong. I want to connect to socket, send generated password and get response.

```
import socket
import sys
import itertools

args = sys.argv

with socket.socket() as client_socket:
    host = args[1]
    port = int(args[2])

    address = (host, port)

    # establish connection
    client_socket.connect(address)

    n = 1
    while True:
        
        # generate different lower/uppercase password
        
        file = open('passwords.txt', 'r')
        for password in file:
            ans = list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), itertools.product(*([letter.lower(), letter.upper()]for letter in password))))

            # send message

            for word in ans:
                message = word.encode(encoding='utf-8')
                client_socket.send(message)

                # receive response

                response = client_socket.recv(1024)
                response = response.decode(encoding='utf-8')

                if response == "Connection success!":
                    print(word)
                    break
            if response == "Connection success!":
                break
                file.close()
```

Comment: i try to run this code and get `list index out of range` on this line:  `host = args[1]`.  I also cannot see the contents of `passwords.txt`, so just assume that the variable, `ans` which is derived from this is correct when in fact it might have errors.

Comment: list index out of range appears bcs no arguments were parsed, this code basically takes arguments in terminal and runs it connecting to parsed host on parsed port, the whole server im connecting to is made by hyperskill,org, the txt file is just textfile of words typically used as passwords, there are like 500 words each ending with newline

Comment: okay,  how can users replicate the problem ?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i belive it might be hard, the whole socket im connecting to is handled by hyperskill,  so u would have to connect to ur local-made socket, that would handle message and send response that depends if the message = password(something that u set on ur socket), i handled the broken pipe error tho, by doing https://pastebin.com/TuHydBhf, to see whats behind it, and its memory error/infinite loop

Comment: im sorry if my instructions are unclear but i've been working on it for 4 hours and im malding already

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Gsjim1Fy i belive u can try tunning this part of code on file https://ufile.io/o8o85zlc